# Which eos testnet has the cheapest fees and ram?

Tags: cpu, testnet, message, memory, memo

I'm looking to work with eos on testnet, but I know there are a few testnet implementations. Which eos testnet has the cheapest ram and cpu where I can use for test my dapp? My dapp mainly sends 500 character messages to other accounts but encrypted. I was thinking of using the memo field, but that requires alot of cpu, so that's why I'm looking for an eos testnet to do these large tests.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the testnet just uses the same fee and ram policy as the mainnet. On testnet, you can just easily ask for faucet tokens for your test.
 The [Junlge Testnet](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#home) is the most popular one.

However, if you really need a network environment with cheaper fees and ram fees for any reason, you might want to consider implementing your own network with modified system contract deployed.

However, I doubt that to be really helpful because if you are planning to implement your dApp on mainnet someday, you will have to find a way to optimize your contract anyway.